# How I can replace [city] to [City] in string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace   `[city], [cIty], [ciTY], ...` with  `[City]`.
I think regex is a good solution, but I am not good at regex.

**Tried Code:**

```
var text = "[City] [CIty] [ciTY] [city] [CITy]";

if (text.Contains("[city]"))
{
    //text = text.Replace("[city]", "[City]");
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[city]", "[City]");
    textbox.Text = text;

    textbox.SelectionStart = textbox.Text.Length;
    textbox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

**Except Output**

> [City] [City] [City] [City] [City]

That is not working, because the `regex` grammar is not completed

Comment: first, you need to ignore case as option in your search, add as parameter : `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` . Second, brackets must be escaped in regex, as they usually have special meaning : `@"\[city\]"`

Comment: Well if the brackets are part of what you try to match, you have to escape them for regex to interpret them correctly.

Comment: @Pac0 That working well, also, How I can solve `if (text.Contains("[city]"))` ?

Comment: @KingStone to check for a regex match, you can use `Regex.IsMatch`, as `string.Contains` doesn't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three points :

1. to match brackets `[]` in the text, you need to escape them in the regex : `@"\[city\]"`
2. Add the option to ignore case `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` in [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_)
3. for the "Contains", it doesn't use regex. Use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_System_TimeSpan_) instead.

So this would turn your code in your question as something like this :

```
var text = textbox.Text;
var pattern = @"\[City\]";

// Will match [city], [cITy], [CITY], but not exactly [City] 
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && !Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern))
{
    text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "[City]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // same code after that 
}
```

Comment: Please update with`Regex.IsMatch` usage for my solution

Comment: @KingStone added full example

Comment: Also, I want to avoid replace `[City]` to `[City]`

Comment: @KingStone you mean, you don't want the "if" entering the block, if the text is already exactly `[City]` ? Then add a condition for an exact match (case sensitive) to the if : `Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && ! Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\[City\]")`

Comment: That working well, but, `[Keyword][City][keyword]` is not updated to `[Keyword][City][Keyword]`, the second `[keyword]` is also ignored with `! Regex.isMathch ...`

Comment: @KingStone, I think the scope of your question is being changed at each comment. It smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/376026)

Comment: What is your actual goal ?

Comment: I upgraded my question

Comment: Also, side note, For applying to a series of `[texts] [texts]`, I'll suggest splitting the string into several small `[texts], and apply this on everyone of them (and then join the string with spaces again if you wish)

Comment: Yes. that can help me, but, your answer is enough

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets, use `Regex.IsMatch` instead of `Contains`, and make the pattern case intensive. You can do this in the regex pattern, but C# has `RegexOptions` built so you can `IgnoreCase`. Here's what it could look like:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\[city\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\[city\]", "[City]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dMgc1k)

You need to escape special characters like brackets in regex, which you can see in the pattern string below. Then, you need to add the regex option RegexOptions.IgnoreCase to ignore casing on when comparing strings against your pattern string.

```
        var testText = @"[CIty] [ciTY] [city] [CITy] [City]";
        Console.WriteLine("Original text: " + testText);

        var pattern = @"\[City\]";

        if(Regex.IsMatch(testText, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            //use the below updated value as you wish
            var updatedStringVal = Regex.Replace(testText, pattern, "[City]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Console.WriteLine("Updated text: " + updatedStringVal);
        }
```

Comment: My input value is `var testText = @"[CIty] [ciTY] [city] [CITy]";`

Comment: But, `var testText = @"[City] [CIty] [ciTY] [city] [CITy]";` is not working

Comment: Check again, it works. Do you still require that [City] will be ignored? If so, you'll have to split the string into a list of strings and check each split element. I can do that for you if that's your requirement, but I didn't see that required in your initial question.

Comment: Yes, thats enough answer

Comment: Okay, if you need it to be split, can you provide the expected input string and I can set that up for you? Can we assume the string elements will always be separated by spaces?